# Kendo UI for Angular Pie Charts is not responsive with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, kendo-chart, kendo-angular-ui

I have created a new component that should show a pie chart inside any place that I place that component, the problem is even with simple component, the pie chart stays as the size of the first render, I got this issue after I changed `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, the problem that I did that because without even the problem does not persist but the resizing start to be laggy and consume more CPU usage during that.

So I got the option to keep that lag and make chart responsive, or change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` and get chart stuck to first time render.

Also, I got many types of charts, like the bar chart and the issue does not seem to be happening with that kind of charts, for now, it is only for my Pie chart.

**my.component.ts:**

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public pieData: { category: string; value: number; active: boolean }[] = [
    {category: 'Complete', value: 123},
    {category: 'Work In Progress', value: 22},
    {category: 'Other', value: 5},
  ];
  constructor(private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
}
```

**my-component.html:**

```
<kendo-chart [seriesColors]="['orange', '#ffe', 'green']">
  <kendo-chart-legend position="top"></kendo-chart-legend>
  <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item [type]="'pie'" [data]="pieData" [field]="'value'" [categoryField]="'category'">
</kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

**my-component.scss**:

```
:host {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
  flex-direction: column;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 760px),
  (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    padding: 2px;
  }
}
```

Comment: The pie chart seems to be resized correctly here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jd47bi?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
Is there anything else specific besides the OnPush strategy?

Comment: @SiliconSoul well, nothing else, I'm using this chart inside some containers with flex layout, but these containers working well, I mean they got resized so I'm not sure if that's the problem, also the chart is inside an Ionic application. but for the component itself, got nothing else.

Comment: I'll try to provide the containers template once I have access to code.

Comment: I came here for overriding series color's scss variables.defined here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/sass-themes, like $series-a and so on, but it didn't work. [seriesColors]="['orange', '#ffe', 'green']" perfectly worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got component with `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (which is a good idea to improve performance) then the good solution is to get `markForCheck()` fired each time you resize the window, but with `debounceTime` so you will get some time to wait before you resize the chart:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    fromEvent(window, 'resize') // get the event observable
      .pipe(debounceTime(200)) // you can change debounceTime to whatever you want
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this._cdRef.markForCheck(); // Here we go
      });
  }
}
```

As the chart itself seems to be responsive and should be redrawn each window change, this will do the trick.